# Angular template with 'element' transclusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given a directive 'wrap-input':

```
scope: {},
transclude: 'element',
template: '<div>' +
          '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' +
          '</div>'
```

Used like this:

```
<input wrap-input></input>
```

I would expect the result to be that it transcludes the entire input element and wraps it in a div, per the template. But it doesn't, it simply leaves a comment in there, unreplaced. How do you get the directive to apply the template where the transcluded element used to be?

Expected:

```
<div>
  <input wrap-input></input>  
</div>
```

Actual

```
<!-- wrapInput:  -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `transclude: 'element'` along with `template` or `templateUrl`, you have to also set `replace: true`. See [#3368](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3368) for the explanation.

And if you want to place the transcluded element between some siblings, you have to use the transclude function in link instead of `ng-transclude` like this:

```
.directive('wrapInput', function() {
  return {
    scope: {},
    transclude: 'element',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div>' +
        '<div>Sibling A</div>' + 
        '<div class="transclution-point"></div>' +
        '<div>Sibling B</div>' +
      '</div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers, transcludeFn) {
      transcludeFn(function (clone) {
        element.find('.transclution-point').replaceWith(clone);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**Example plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/tkMCZB6vxNOwSiLwYbkp?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [wrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) function provided by angular on elements

```
link: function(scope, element, attributes){
    element.wrap('<div />');
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fa54a/

Comment: Wrap is nice for a simple wrapper, but say I want it to be part of a larger template.

Comment: Like wrapped in a div with a bunch of sibling elements, etc.

Comment: You have full access to the DOM so you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/csbarnes/c9PhB/. Just remember to keep DOM insertions to as few statements as possible.